# Hadoop Spring multiple inputs and mappers in a job

Tags: java, spring, hadoop

How to specify multiple input files and their respective format in a Job tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd">

   <context:property-placeholder location="hadoop.properties"/>

   <configuration>
      fs.default.name=${hd.fs}
      yarn.resourcemanager.address=${hd.rm}
      mapreduce.framework.name=${mr.fw}
   </configuration>

   <job id="wordcountJob"
      input-path="${wordcount.input.path}" 
      output-path="${wordcount.output.path}"
      mapper="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.TokenizerMapper"
      reducer="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.IntSumReducer"/>
</beans:beans>
```

Like we can a specify in simple java program.

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, firstPath, FirstInputFormat.class, FirstMap.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, sencondPath, SecondInputFormat.class, SecondMap.class);
```

I goggled a lot even i checked its xsd file. I did not find any attribute so how can we specify multiple inputs in a job?

Comment: I didn't find any solution for multiple file in Spring Hadoop integration. So i used native java code to submit Hadoop Job.